# GXT prevent action execution if validation fails

Tags: gwt, gxt

i'd like to know if there's a way to use the validation state of a form's fields to authorize/prevent an action to be performed.

It may be clearer with an example. 
I'm displaying a form with mandatory fields to be filled in order to create a record in db, and a save button to do so.

I'd like the save button action to be prevented if the static validation of the form is not ok.
Is there a built-in mechanism to do so?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FormPanel` has a method [`isValid`](http://docs.sencha.com/gxt/3/com/sencha/gxt/widget/core/client/form/FormPanel.html#isValid()) that will automatically validate all the contained fields (implementing `IsField`) by calling `isValid` on them. If any returns `false`, the form's `isValid` method will also return `false`.

You can use the `FormPanel.isValid` call in a `ClickHandler` for your form's save button and just return without doing anything if it's not valid.

```java
@UiHandler("formPanel")
void onSave(ClickEvent event) {
    if (!formPanel.isValid()) {
        return;
    }

    saveToDb();
}
```